# See .sql file in Tableau Public

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I am new to Tableau and I cannot figure out how to get the application to open a .SQL file. It is a query that I have to explain but I don't know how to display the tables in it.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau public cannot connect to sql databases. See the docs here for more information. https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-9135#subhead20

Comment: Does the Personal edition have this option? What can I use to see the file properly?

Comment: A .sql file is normally just a query. You can use any text editor to open it.